# Pass enum case as parameter in swift 4

Tags: swift, parameters, enums

So I´m trying to build a framework with a function like this

```
public func logScreen(screen: SomeEnum){
    print(screen.rawValue)
}
```

and i want to pass as parameter a case of a string enum that is defined in the project that will make use of this framework

Comment: ok, if the enum is defined out of the framework, I don't think you can do it. you should define the enum in your framework, or another framework that your framework can access.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I´ve been reading documentation of how to extend enums, convert them into arrays and back to enums but I haven´t achived anything so far

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this directly. But using swift protocol, you can achieve your goal I believe. You may review my idea.

First, you need to define a protocol in your framework. Say in you Framework class.

```
public protocol SomeEnum {
    var rawValue: String { get }
}
```

Inside your framework class, you define your code:

```
public func logScreen(screen: SomeEnum){
    print(screen.rawValue)
}
```

Now in your project, you can declare the enum and inherite the framework 
 protocol. Say for example in your project:

```
public enum MyEnum: SomeEnum {
    case test
    case debug

    public var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .test:
            return "test"
        case .debug:
            return "Debug"
        }
    }
}
```

Now use the method from your project like below:

```
yourframeworkclass.logScreen(screen: MyEnum.test)
```

Comment: This is what `RawRepresentable` is for.